# Windows 8 to Windows 7: downgrading vs. clean install?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I'm looking to buy a new laptop soon. However, it seems most of them are running Windows 8, and I prefer to work with Windows 7.

From what I've heard, only the Professional Edition of Windows 8 has downgrade rights. If I want to "upgrade" to Windows 7 from a non-Professional edition of Windows 8, is there anything to prevent me from wiping the OS and doing a clean install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. As long as you own a full retail copy of W7 and have the appropriate installation media (DVD or USB) and the corresponding license key to boot you are cleared to go. The first part of doing a "clean" installation of an operating system is wiping the hard drive.

Be ware though that your warranty for the computer, at least the software part will most likely be void if you do this. Or more likely, if you get any problems and want them to fix it, they will probably wipe tha hard drive and do a "factory reset", reverting it back to W8.